# What needs to be set up on Unix for a java web client?

Tags: java, web-services, unix, client, jdeveloper

I created a client using proxy in Oracle JDeveloper to call web service. JDeveloper deployed automatically and the code works well under windows environment. But now I'm required to migrate the code to unix server. I deployed the project to a .war file and copy it to unix which cannot be executed correctly using "jar" command.

Could anybody give me a whole picture or a high-level step-by-step instruction about what I need to set up to execute war on unix? I'm new to this area, and for now I got some suggestions like installing a Tomcat first.

What I have now:
1. a war file including .class, .java, WEB-INF, META-INF, MANIFEST.MF deployed from JDeveloper
2. JDK 1.6.0_25 installed on unix usr/java/
3. Tomcat installed on unix, but not under bin or local or usr directory(is it ok?)

Some specific questions:
1. what else do I need?
2. where to drop the .war?
3. do I need to unzip or re-compile the war?
4. how can I run the main class in the war?

Errors poped-up now:
1. cannot find main class
2. I tried to un-zip war and compile the class including main, and get "cannot find symbol" for the webservice specified classes' name.

Thanks to whoever attempt to help!

Comment: Where are the errors popping up? When you add your war to the webapps in tomcat, it should be accessed by pointing your web browser to your machine and port combination plus the path to your app. Did you do that? You might also want to take a look at the manager app in Tomcat: http://tomcasthostname:tomcatport/manager/html

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question probably should've been asked on ServerFault instead of here, sounds like you got all you need. Try dropping the .war on tomcat's webapps directory.

Comment: You mean http://serverfault.com/ ? Sorry for disturbing others... Thanks for referring this :) I'm really green hand.

Comment: But... After copy the war file under webapps/ I still got "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from webapp2.war". I'm sure when deployed I specified the class which includes main class for MANIFEST

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just drop the .war file in $CATALINA_BASE/webapps and tomcat should pick it up when you start it.

$CATALINA_BASE is where you installed tomcat, unless you've configured tomcat for multiple bases.

Comment: Thanks for reply :) but it still doesn't work for me. Please see the comments above and below...

Answer (score 0):

You only need a war file if you are developing web application. From what you describe, you need to create a zip file which contains all the libraries and classes you need and copy it to Unix. Then you unpack it and execute it using java command.
Alternatively you can create a jar file with all dependencies included using [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) and execute your code using jar command.

Comment: Thanks, I use "java -jar webapp2.war" command, and get still "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from webapp2.war" error... I checked all I can when deployed in jdeveloper. Is there a way to check whether I include libs and dependencies right in my .war?

Comment: You can unpack war file and see what is in there... But if you run your code outside of container with java command you should not use war files